# SQLite limit query ignores the starting row number

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch rows with a `LIMIT` clause. But what I'm getting is all the rows until the limit. For example if I execute:
(this is in the QSqlQueryModel)

```
QString queryFullTextSearch = "SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 20,40";
QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(queryFullTextSearch, queryDB);
```

What I'm getting is the rows from 0 to 40. And if next I execute it from 40 to 80,
what I'm getting is the rows from 0 to 80.

Is there a problem in the way I'm executing the query?

Comment: A `limit` clause without an `order by` clause is _always_ suspicious.

Comment: i added order by < table _ col > but no good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, try:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 20 OFFSET 40
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) his syntax is correct.

Comment: Yes, it says: "Instead of a separate OFFSET clause, the LIMIT clause may specify two scalar expressions separated by a comma. In this case, the first expression is used as the OFFSET expression and the second as the LIMIT expression. This is counter-intuitive, as when using the OFFSET clause the second of the two expressions is the OFFSET and the first the LIMIT. This is intentional - it maximizes compatibility with other SQL database systems."

Comment: I got your point, but I assumed that he knows what he's doing. His SELECT statement should return rows from 20 to 60, but he gets 0 to 40 instead, like the OFFSET clause was never there. Nevertheless, he should try using `LIMIT 40 OFFSET 20` to see if he has more luck with the alternative syntax.